# Expected expression before ‘/’ token

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors

Im trying to write a simple calculator program where it only has two operands and 4 basic operations: "+ - * /".

I want to implement a function where it exits the program if it detects the incorrect operation.

I have it in an `if()` function as `if(op != + - * /)`
However, I keep getting this error code:

[image: error in question]

Heres the code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)

{

char op;
double first, second;

printf("Enter operater sympbol:\n");
scanf("%c", &op);

switch (op)
{
    
    if(op != + - * /)
{
    printf("Error. Unidentified operation\n");
    exit(0);
}

else
{
    case '+':
    printf("%.lf + %.lf = %.lf", first, second, first + second);
    break;

    case '-':
    printf("%.lf - %.lf = %.lf", first, second, first - second);
    break;

    case '*':
    printf("%.lf * %.lf = %.lf", first, second, first * second);
    break;

    case '/':
    printf("%.lf / %.lf = %.lf", first, second, first / second);
     
}
    
   
}



printf("Enter the numbers you wish to compute.(MAX TWO):\n");
scanf("%lf %lf", &first, &second);



return (0);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: For starters, there is a difference between `*` and `'*'`.

Comment: @chris122: Stack Overflow is not intended to be a personal help site or a tutorial service. [Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer—if the information that you need already exists, then you should be able to find it before asking.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Before asking a question like this, a person should get an introduction-to-C book, read it, and work through its exercises.

Answer (score 1):

That's simply not how the syntax of C works. What you are trying to do has to be written as follows:

```
if (op != '+' && op != '-' && op != '*' && op != '/') {
  ...
}
```

The error seemingly only fails on `/`, but that's because all other operators can be used as unary operators (positive numeric value, negated numeric value, pointer dereference; respectively).

But you are trying to compare character values and `+` is not a character literal, but an operator. `'+'` is a character literal.

Note that you are mixing up different syntaxes/statements. You are combining switch and if. While that might be syntactically correct, it will likely not give you the expected result.

Since you are using switch/case, valid operators do not need to be checked before. Simply handle all unknown operators in the `default:` case:

```
switch (op)
{
  case '+':
    printf("%.lf + %.lf = %.lf", first, second, first + second);
    break;

  case '-':
    printf("%.lf - %.lf = %.lf", first, second, first - second);
    break;

  case '*':
    printf("%.lf * %.lf = %.lf", first, second, first * second);
    break;

  case '/':
    printf("%.lf / %.lf = %.lf", first, second, first / second);
    break;

  default:
    printf("Error. Unidentified operator: '%c'\n", op);
    exit(0);
}
```